# Watchify command line deleting bundle on file changes

Tags: reactjs, watchify

When I run `watchify` (latest version) the 1st time it works, creates the bundle, web app loads OK. But change a file, save it, and watchify creates an empty bundle file i.e. it's blank. I have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and restart watchify for it to detect the changes.

```
npm install -g watchify 
npm install reactify
watchify --debug -t reactify ./src/app.jsx -o ../build/app.js
```

Comment: Can you give more information? OS, node version, arch, etc.  This probably belongs on github in an issue, though.

Comment: Mac OS X, v10.9.5, NodeJS v0.12.1, Watchify v3.1.0. Not sure what you mean by Arch?

Comment: Try it with 0.10 latest.  Install watchify locally after you downgrade, and do ./node_modules/.bin/watchify.

Comment: The issue seems to vanish about every 10th time I restart `watchify`. I'd rather not revert back to an old version of Node, going to try `https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon` if nodemon doesn't work I'll give Gulp a shot.

Comment: A lot of things don't work right with 0.12 yet.  At least install nvm so you can switch versions easily.  Voting to close because there's not enough information to provide an answer.